# gcc cross compiler to dump RTL file

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I am using a gcc cross compiler arm-elf-gcc-4.4.2. It can compile normally; however, when I want to view the intermediate file by adding `-fdump-final-insns`, it gives me the following error:

```
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdump-final-insns"
```

Is there any other way to dump the intermediate file?

Comment: That presumably means that your cross-compiler was built without the necessary support for that option, or its version pre-dates that option.

Comment: isit part of the gdb lib ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org), as we can see in document https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc.pdf

`-fdump-final-insns`

first appears in GCC 4.5.4. In `arm-elf-gcc-4.4.2` it did not exist yet.